# How does the Monochromacy color space simulation work in Android?

Tags: android, colors, monochrome, color-blindness

I recently read about [desaturation works](https://docs.gimp.org/2.10/en/gimp-filter-desaturate.html) in GIMP. Since I am a heavy smartphone grey-mode user, I wondered how the colour conversion works in Android.

I did not expect it to be a naïve [desaturation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV#Disadvantages) as overall it looks very pleasant; I was more expecting [LAB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIELAB_color_space) Lightness (L*). However, my tests showed that it does not use perceptual lightness – in fact, I could not replicate this effect in GIMP.

I tried searching for this but did not find any results.